# Module not found in case of a module B being exported with eclipse and containing another module A

Tags: java, eclipse, module, jar

I have a problem in eclipse when exporting a JAR file of a module project B that itself includes another module A contained in a jar file. In this case, when I try to import the exported module, I get a java.lang.module.FindException.

In my example, project A is a modular project with only one class AClass:

```java
package a;

public class AClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("From module A");
    }
}
```

The module-info of project A is:

```java
module modulea {
    exports a;
}
```

The project B is also a modular project including an export as Jar file of project A. It contains only one class BClass:

```java
package b;

import a.AClass;

public class BClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AClass.main(args);
    }
}
```

The module-info of project B is:

```java
module moduleb {
    requires transitive modulea;

    exports b;
}
```

When I run the project B, I get the expected result: From module A

The project C is also a modular project including an export as Jar file of project B. The project B is exported as illustrated below:

[image]

and the content of the B jar file is illustrated below:

[image]

Project C contains only a single class CClass:

```java
package c;

public class CClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("ok");
    }
}
```

The module-info of project C is:

```java
module modulec {
    requires moduleb;
}
```

When I run the project C, I get the error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module modulea not found, required by moduleb
```

I think the problem comes from that project C does not find the module A required by module B, despite the fact that module A is contained in the lib folder of the jar of project B.
But I don't know how to solve this type of problem. 
The question is: How to export in a jar file a modular project B containing another module A with Eclipse?

**Eclipse:**

```
Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0)
Build id: 20190917-1200
```

**JVM:**

```
openjdk version "13-BellSoft" 2019-09-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 13-BellSoft+33)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 13-BellSoft+33, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: A JAR can contain only one module, not multiple modules (this is a limitation of the Java Platform Module System). But in your case, the `B.jar` seems to contain the `A.jar` (module A plus module B), right?

Comment: Yes, I added an illustration that shows the content of the B.jar file that contains the A.jar module. I understand that one module cannot contain another module. But in this case, why does Eclipse allow me to export the jar in this way if this is not possible? And what is the best solution to that situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, the `B.jar` contains the `A.jar` (module A plus module B). But the Java Platform Module System (JPMS) allows **only one module per JAR**, not multiple modules in one JAR.

You have the following two options:

- **Not including the `A.jar` in the `B.jar`** and in project C use both module JARs, `A.jar` and `B.jar` via the *Modulepath*
- **Not using JPMS** by deleting the `module-info.java` file in project C (in this case, including the `A.jar` in the `B.jar` works; if you don't use `jlink`, then the extra effort for JPMS doesn't bring any benefit)

Comment: Okay, I understand. However, I don't understand why Eclipse exports the jar file in this way. We cannot import them in another modular project. It makes no sense for Eclipse to put one module in another if it is not allowed by the Java Platform Module System.

Comment: I agree, the JAR export dialog should display at least a warning. Please report it to Eclipse or even better, suggest a patch.

Comment: I agree, I don't think I can make a patch but I can make a report to Eclipse this weekend.

Comment: @SceDev Thanks. You can [report it here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=JDT&component=UI).

Comment: Thanks, I'll take care of it this weekend.